# Compare standard deviations from medians?

Tags: st.statistics

Let $G = (U, V, E)$ be a bipartite graph with $|U| = |V|$, $|U|$ large.  If the median degree of a node in *U* is 4, and the median degree of a node in *V* is 7, is there a way to tell whether the degree distribution of *U* or *V* has a greater standard deviation?

Answer (score 2):

Not with this information alone. Indeed, nothing you assumed contradicts the maximal degree's being 11 or less and in that case you can just make another graph with degrees $11-d_j$ instead of $d_j$ (all you really need for the existence of the bipartite graph with given degrees is that the total degree of vertices in $U$ is the same as the total degree of vertices in $V$; this is literally true if you allow multiple edges and true under the assumption that all degrees are much less than $|U|,|V|$ if you do not). But that other graph has the medians reversed and the same standard deviations as the original one.